# JavaScriptCore methods with parameters not being exported from class

Tags: javascript, swift, macos, javascriptcore

I'm running into some weird issues with `JavaScriptCore`. Whenever I add a method to my class that has a parameter, it doesn't seem to be exported (or is exported with a weird name). For example:

```
import Cocoa
import JavaScriptCore

@objc
public protocol MyObjectExport: JSExport {
    var property: Int { get set }
    init()
    func test() -> String
    func doNothing(num: Int)
    func squared(num: Int) -> Int
    func sum(a:Int, _ b: Int) -> Int
}

@objc
public class MyObject: NSObject, MyObjectExport {
    public var property: Int {
        get {
            return 5
        }
        set {
            print("New value \(newValue)")
        }
    }

    public required override init() {

    }

    public func test() -> String {
        return "Tested"
    }

    public func doNothing(num: Int) {

    }

    public func squared(num: Int) -> Int {
        return num * num
    }

    public func sum(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a + b
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let context = JSContext()!

        context.exceptionHandler = { context, exc in
            print("Exception \(exc)")
        }

        context.setObject(MyObject.self, forKeyedSubscript: NSString(string: "MyObject"))
        context.evaluateScript("var obj = new MyObject()")
        print(context.evaluateScript("obj"))
        print(context.evaluateScript("obj.test()"))
        print(context.evaluateScript("obj.doNothing(5)"))
        print(context.evaluateScript("obj.squared(5)"))
        print(context.evaluateScript("obj.sum(5,5)"))

    }
}
```

*Note that this has to be tested in a macOS app. JavaScriptCore acts even weirder in a playground.*

When this is ran, I get the output

```
<TestProject.MyObject: 0x608000001180>
Tested
Exception Optional(TypeError: obj.doNothing is not a function. (In 'obj.doNothing(5)', 'obj.doNothing' is undefined))
undefined
Exception Optional(TypeError: obj.squared is not a function. (In 'obj.squared(5)', 'obj.squared' is undefined))
undefined
Exception Optional(TypeError: obj.sum is not a function. (In 'obj.sum(5,5)', 'obj.sum' is undefined))
undefined
```

As you can see, the initiator works and so does the method `test`. However, all other methods with parameters do not seem to be exported or they are exported under some other method name I can not find.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Swift 3, the first parameter is no longer longer unnamed by default.

You cannot call `doNothing`, `squared`, and `sum` from Swift code like this:

```
doNothing(5)
squared(5)
sum(5,5)
```

You must include the argument names:

```
doNothing(num: 5)
squared(num: 5)
sum(a: 5,5)    //argument name not required for 'b' because it is '_'
```

Those methods get the Objective-C selectors `doNothingWithNum:`, `squaredWithNum:`, and `sumWithA::`.  These are exported to JavaScript with the following rules, according to [the documentation for JSExport](https://developer.apple.com/reference/javascriptcore/jsexport):

> When exporting a selector that takes one or more arguments, JavaScriptCore generates a corresponding function name using the following conversion:
>
> - All colons are removed from the selector.
> - Any lowercase letter that had followed a colon is capitalized.

So `doNothing`, `squared`, and `sum` are called `doNothingWithNum()`, `squaredWithNum()`, and `sumWithA()`.  You have to either change your JavaScript to call the methods with those names:

```
print(context.evaluateScript("obj.doNothingWithNum(5)"))
print(context.evaluateScript("obj.squaredWithNum(5)"))
print(context.evaluateScript("obj.sumWithA(5,5)"))
```

Or change your class & protocol definitions to remove the parameter names:

```
@objc
public protocol MyObjectExport: JSExport {
    var property: Int { get set }
    init()
    func test() -> String
    func doNothing(_ num: Int)
    func squared(_ num: Int) -> Int
    func sum(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int
}

@objc
public class MyObject: NSObject, MyObjectExport {
    public var property: Int {
        get {
            return 5
        }
        set {
            print("New value \(newValue)")
        }
    }

    public required override init() {

    }

    public func test() -> String {
        return "Tested"
    }

    public func doNothing(_ num: Int) {

    }

    public func squared(_ num: Int) -> Int {
        return num * num
    }

    public func sum(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 3

/// create a protocol,Inheritance JSExport

```
@objc protocol MYPJSExport: JSExport {
    var sum: Int {get set}

    func doNothing()

    func squared(_ num: Int) -> Int
    func add(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int

    func add(num: Int) -> Int
    func add(num1: Int, num2: Int) -> Int
    func add(num1: Int, _ num2: Int) -> Int
//    func add(_ num1: Int, num2: Int) -> Int //the first external parameter is omitted，JS can't call
}
```

//note：@objc  can't be lost

```
@objc class MYPObject: NSObject, MYPJSExport {
    var sum: Int = 0 {
        willSet{
            print("newValue: \(newValue)  |CurrentThread: \(Thread.current)")
        }
        didSet{
            print("oldValue: \(oldValue)  |CurrentThread: \(Thread.current)")
        }
    }

    func add(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a + b
    }
    func doNothing(){
        print("doNothing--")
    }
    func squared(_ num: Int) -> Int {
        return num * num
    }

    func add(num: Int) -> Int {
        return num + 10
    }
    func add(num1: Int, num2: Int) -> Int {
        return num1 + num2
    }
    func add(num1: Int, _ num2: Int) -> Int {
        return num1 * num2
    }


//    func add(_ num1: Int, num2: Int) -> Int {
//        return (num1 + num2) * 2
//    }
}
```

### JS Call Swift Method on ViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
let obj: MYPObject = MYPObject()
let context:JSContext = JSContext()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    context.exceptionHandler = { (context, exception) in
        guard let exce = exception else { return }
        context!.exception = exce
        print("JS exception: \(exce)")
    }
    let block: @convention(block) () -> () = {
        print("++++++Begin Log++++++")
        let args = JSContext.currentArguments()
        for jsVal in args! {
            print(jsVal)
        }
        print("---End Log------")
    }
    context.setObject(block, forKeyedSubscript: NSString(string: "log"))
    context.setObject(obj, forKeyedSubscript: NSString(string: "Swiftobj"))


    print(context.evaluateScript("log(Swiftobj.doNothing(5))"))
    print(context.evaluateScript("log(Swiftobj.squared(5))"))
    print(context.evaluateScript("log(Swiftobj.add(5,5))"))
    print(context.evaluateScript("log(Swiftobj.addWithNum(5))"))
    print(context.evaluateScript("log(Swiftobj.addWithNum1Num2(10,10))"))
    print(context.evaluateScript("log(Swiftobj.addWithNum1(10,10))"))
//        print(context.evaluateScript("log(Swiftobj.addWithNum2(10,10))")) // 'Swiftobj.addWithNum2' is undefined

    context.evaluateScript("Swiftobj.sum = Swiftobj.add(2,3)")
    print(context.evaluateScript("log(Swiftobj.sum)"))
    print("obj.sum: \(obj.sum)")
}
```

}

Comment: [Stack Overflow generally works in English](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/); please make sure your post is as useful as possible to others by translating the parts that are not in English.

Comment: OK, got it. I have change it in English;